# Equivalent C++ macro to Rust's include_str

Tags: c++, rust

Does C++ have a macro like Rust's `include_str!`? Macros similar to `include!` or `include_bytes` would also meet my requirements.

Comment: isn't `#include` will include anything ?

Comment: No, I need to access the included content with a variable. As I know, I can't store the included content in a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no standard way to do this. There's proposal [P1040R6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1040r6.html) for `std::embed`.

If you want to experiment with this right now, check out https://github.com/ThePhD/embed (which is by the author of the aforementioned proposal). You'll need to patch your compiler though, so it doesn't seem very portable.

Comment: There's also [P1967](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1967r2.pdf), which is the preprocessor-level feature that was split in R6 from P1040 (it was one proposal in earlier revisions). And [WG14 N2499](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2499.pdf), the same `#embed` proposal for C.

Comment: In addition, the paper also lists a few ways to achieve this in existing compilers. But they're ugly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I was searching!